# Legend not showing in ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, legend

Help! Trying to plot a scatter plot, with a regression line, and a horizontal line marking a target level. Below is my code - I can't seem to figure out how to get the legend to show up.

```
ggplot(clean_1br, aes(x = as.Date(Date), y = LN_Conc)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = '#2A788E', shape = 19)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = 'darkgrey', linetype = 'solid'), method = 'lm', se = TRUE, level = 0.90, fill = 'lightgrey') +
  geom_hline(aes(color = 'black', linetype = 'dashed'), yintercept = 6.5, color = 'black') +
  labs(title = 'Determination of First-Order Rate Constant', x = 'Date', y = expression(paste("LN Conc (",mu,"g/L)", sep=""))) +
  ylim(6.5, 8) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('LN Conc' = '#2A788E', 'Linear (LN Conc)' = 'darkgrey', 'LN Screening Level' = 'black')) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c('LN Conc' = 20, 'Linear (LN Conc)' = NA, 'LN Screening Level' = NA)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('LN Conc' = NA, 'Linear (LN Conc)' = 'solid', 'LN Screening Level' = 'dashed')) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "horizontal")
```

Also, if you could help me add the regression equation and R^2 - that would be fantastic too!

I've tried too many things to remember and list here. For the code above - the graph looks exactly as it should except the legend doesn't show up.

Comment: You are mis-using `aes`thetics. Generally, one would use `aes(color=VariableName)` (_not quoted_) or `aes(..), color="#2A788E"` (outside `aes`, a literal color to apply to all points in that geom). By assigning literal strings inside `aes`, you're skipping much of what it's intended for.

Comment: But first ... welcome to SO, Whit Altman! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a great start here), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Here's a great intro to ggplot2 from it's original creator: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html

Comment: When using `scale_*_manual` and a named-vector for `values=` (which is a good thing), the LHS of the `=`s should be the values observed in the column that you have applied to `aes(color=)`. For instance, if you find all of `c("LN Conc", "Linear (LN Conc)", ...)` in a column named `clean_1br$quux`, then you would do something like `geom_point(aes(color=quux), shape=19)`, and then keep `scale_color_manual` as you have it now.